# Upgrade read-only database

Tags: android, database

I'm using `SQLiteAssetHelper` for importing ready databases into my app.
Now I want to release a 2nd version of my database, but when users update the app, the database in not updating. I see documentation and saw I must use `setForcedUpgrade()`, but i don't know where to use it, I'll appreciate if you guide me. :)

MyDatabase.java :

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}}
```

And I read database with these:

```
    MyDatabase my;

    SQLiteDatabase sq;

    my = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());

    sq = my.getWritableDatabase();
```

Thanks by the way.

Comment: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you should use SQLiteOpenHelper (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Inherid your own class and overwrite `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

For your example:

```
    public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

//FORCE UPGRADE BY DELETING OLD DATABASE
setForcedUpgrade(DATABASE_VERSION);

}}
```

Comment: I think this should be considered the proper answer for this question since it uses `SQLiteAssetHelper` [upgrading via overwrite](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#upgrades-via-overwrite) rather than `SQLiteOpenHelper `.